# Open File (double click) not sending arguments to C# applitacion

Tags: c#, winforms, arguments

I'm working on an application that opens a file extension. The first thing I do is check the file path that was opened. This piece of code works perfectly on some PC's but refuses to work properly on another PC running Windows 7. 
Here's the code:

```
if (args.Length > 0)
{
    if (!args[0].EndsWith(".myext1") && !args[0].EndsWith(".myext2"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error.");
        Application.Exit();
    }
 }
 else
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Select File.");
     OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
     if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         this.FilePath = open.FileName;
  }
```

In this case, it goest directly to the 'else' statement, i.e., there's no arguments.

As I said, this code works perfectly on most cases, so my question is, what could  be causing that this computer running windows 7 sends absolutely no arguments when oppened by a double click?

Comment: How did you associate the program with the extension?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I included the association in the installshield project I created for the app, but I don't think this is an issue, because when I open the file with said extension, it does open the application it's supposed to open, but it's not sending any arguments. if I print arguments.length it returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possibly a user rights issue.  You should try creating a shortcut to the application and pass the file you want to open as the first argument.  Right-click the shortcut and choose Run as Administrator.  If that works then you know it is a rights issue.  You might have the exe setup to run as administrator.  By default, the windows shell is not running as administrator.  So, if the exe is set to run as administrator the shell will not be allowed to pass an argument to it.  You'll have to right-click the exe and choose to not run as administrator if you want the shell to be able to pass arguments to it.  This happened to me before.  It is only a suggestion.  I would have posted it as a comment, but I thought the description might be too long for a single comment.

Comment: thank you, but the problem is not running the application. The application runs perfectly. The problem is that the application is supposed to run when I open a file with certain extension. When I do this in another PC (double click a file with my extension), it opens my application and sends the path of said file as an argument (like it's supposed to do), but I'm not able to do this on this machine in particular.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "but I'm not able to do this on this machine in particular."  The rights issue I'm describing will only prevent the argument from being passed.  It does not prevent the application from being launched.  So, if the file type is associated with that exe it will launch it but might not pass the argument to it.  You should try creating the shortcut.

Comment: sorry, I guess I didn't explain myselft correctly. I get what you're saying now. And that's exactly my problem, it's not passing the argument. Let me give it a shot with the shortcut that you described. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/361816/pass-command-line-arguments-to-windows-open-with)

I believe you should run an elevated ftype and assoc command on the Windows 7 PC in order to tell What to send as arguments.